# Verificar diretórios vazios e pegar saída do comando

Tags: bash, shell-script

Eu possuo uma pasta chamada `work` e dentro dela tenho 2 pastas: `p1` e `p2`. Como posso saber se as pastas `p1` e `p2` estão vazias ?

Eu tenho o seguinte comando

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | cut -d\  -f2-
```

Com este comando eu sei se tem arquivos dentro das pastas...aí me retorna no terminal a pasta e o arquivo, caso não tenha arquivos não retorna nada.

Como posso fazer pra saber o que foi o retorno? Exemplo:

`Se tem arquivo(s), print "Achou", senão print "Não achou"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar um *if* na *command line*. Ficaria o seguinte:

```
if [ `find . -type f | wc -l` -ge 1 ] ; then echo "Existe arquivos"; else echo "Nao existe arquivos"; fi
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Ou então procura directamente as pastas vazias:

```
find . -type d -empty
```